# Dockerize Flask Application with machine learning model

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, docker-compose, devops

I have Flask application using machine learning model from [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/cardiffnlp/twitter-xlm-roberta-base-sentiment), the model size is 1.1 GB, and I am trying to find the best way to download this model, so the model is downloaded during building the docker image, using download.py file

Docker File

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Download the model, tokenizer, and config
COPY download.py .
RUN python download.py
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  flask-app:
    container_name: flask-app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

My questions

- What is the best practice to do so in general ?
- Every time I am trying to build the image the model is downloading, I want to download it only once, how should I do this ?

Answer (score -1):

To optimize your Dockerfile and ensure the model is downloaded only once, you can follow these steps:

Use multi-stage Docker build: This approach allows you to use different stages during the Docker build process. You can download the model in one stage and then copy it to the final stage, avoiding redundant downloads during subsequent builds.

Utilize Docker cache: Docker uses a cache during the build process to speed up subsequent builds. By structuring your Dockerfile appropriately, you can take advantage of this cache mechanism to avoid downloading the model if the code and requirements have not changed.

Here's how you can modify your Dockerfile to incorporate these practices:

Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1: Download the model, tokenizer, and config
FROM python:3.8 AS builder
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY download.py .
RUN python download.py

# Stage 2: Build the actual image
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy only the necessary files from the builder stage (model and downloaded files)
COPY --from=builder /code/model_directory /code/model_directory

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

With this approach, the first stage (builder) will download the model and related files. The second stage will only copy the necessary files from the builder stage and use the Docker cache for unchanged parts of the code and requirements.

Additionally, you may want to modify the download.py script to check if the model already exists before downloading it again. If the model file already exists, the script can skip the download process. This way, even if you rebuild the image, the model download will only happen when it's not present.

By following these practices, you can minimize unnecessary downloads and optimize your Docker build process.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, madhu a!

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).